# when I should choose boost spirit attr_cast over semantic action

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

That's it the title say it all.

In the context of boost spirit qi, I do not understand when attr_cast will be preferable over semantic action that converts the value, say: [_val = convert(_1)]

Answer (score 3):

Attr_cast can be useful to help spirit detect slightly incompatible attribute types (e.g. `attr_cast<optional<bool>>` to change 'Just bool' into 'Maybe bool') and to define at which level attributes are going to be split, e.g.

```
 string = '0' >> (repeat(3) [ qi::char_("0-9") ] % "'")
```

could have different attribute compatibility from

```
 string = '0' >> attr_cast(repeat(3) [ qi::char_("0-9") ]) % "'"
```

See also:

- as<>
- as_string
- as_wstring

In other words, I feel `attr_cast` is not primarily useful to cast attribute *values*, but rather to annotate attribute *types* in sub-expressions with the "intended exposed attribute structure", without having to resort to declaring a `qi::rule<>` to annotate that.

I only use `attr_cast` as 'light-weight' rules.